# From combinatorial entropy to Shannon entropy

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, information-theory, entropy

This blog, [Shannon entropy](http://lagodiuk.github.io/computer_science/2016/10/31/entropy.html), by Yurii Lahodiuk shows the link (derivation) of Shannon entropy from basic combinatorics. I would like to know the first person that made this combinatorial interpretation of Shannon entropy.

> Who is the first person who gave this interpretation? What is the first appearance of this combinatorial interpretation in the literature?

Comment: Yurii Lahodiuk is a member here known as @stemm

Comment: FWIW there's a beta [History of Science and Mathematics](//hsm.stackexchange.com) stack where this question would also be on topic. To be clear, I am not advising that you cross-post. However, if you don't get an answer here you could request migration and take your chances there.

Comment: This will surely be someone like Boltzmann or Gibbs from the 19th century. The accepted answer links to lecture notes from 2009, which is definitely not the origin of this argument!!

Comment: My understanding is that Shannon himself was aware of this link, which is why he called in Entropy to begin with. The combinatorial approach was well known from Statistical Mechanics of Boltzmann, Gibbs, and others of the 19th century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written the blog post: http://lagodiuk.github.io/computer_science/2016/10/31/entropy.html.

Frankly speaking, I have learnt about this interpretation from the exam-preparation notes, which I have found here: https://github.com/dmitriykovalev/nsu.videosoft.org/blob/master/assets/content/pdf/entropy.pdf

Which seems to be a part of the course taught by Kovalev Dmitry Sergeyevich "Data presentation and compression": http://nsu.videosoft.org/2009/.

Comment: Thanks Yurii, I have enjoyed reading your nice blog.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Mohammad!

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipeida, this [interpretation (known as the maximum entropy principle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy) was given by Jaynes (based on a suggestion by Wallis). Here is an excerpt:

> The principle was first expounded by E. T. Jaynes in two papers in 1957 where he emphasized a natural correspondence between statistical mechanics and information theory. In particular, Jaynes offered a new and very general rationale why the Gibbsian method of statistical mechanics works. He argued that the entropy of statistical mechanics and the information entropy of information theory are basically the same thing.